# How to prove $f(x) = \frac{e^{x^{2}} \sqrt {\sin x}}{\cos x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ using limit theorems?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

could you please give a hint for this?

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{x^{2}} \sqrt {\sin x}}{\cos x}$$

I thought to approach breaking the function pieces by taking $e^{x^{2}} \sqrt{\sin x}$ as one function and $\cos x$ as another function separately.

By looking at the graph I figured out that only the right limit at $0$ exists for $\sqrt {\sin x}$. I can say $(0,1]$ the function is clearly continuous.

I could show,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} e^{x^{2}} \sqrt {\sin x} \leq 1 $$

How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. $f$ is continuous and $f\ge 0$  implies $\sqrt{f}$ is also continuous.
2. $f, g$ are continuous implies $fg$ is also continuous
3. $f, g$ are continuous and $\forall x$ ,$ g(x)\neq 0$ then $\frac{f}{g}$ is also continuous.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are fine but how can I say $\sqrt {sin x} $ is continuous at $0$ while it does not have a left limit?

Comment: @Lucifer since you're considering it on $[0,1]$, you only consider one-sided limits at the endpoints

Comment: @Lucifer I think you need to study from the basic https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20continuous%20function,in%20value%2C%20known%20as%20discontinuities.

Comment: oh got it. I'm sorry I was confused

Comment: @Lucifer It's a good exercise for you to prove $1, 2,3$ using  definition of continuity ( sequences, $\epsilon-\delta$).

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you. I already proved the 2nd one and 3rd one. I'll try the 1st one as well. Appreciate your support

Comment: @Lucifer Excellent. Learn and enjoy.